# Change directory when picking an icon

Tags: icons, ubuntu-mate

Is it possible to have another directory open when changing an icon?

I want the directory /home/andy/ICONS/ to be selected.

[image]

The directory opened sometimes changes depending on the program I want to change the icon for.

I am using Ubuntu Mate 18.04.

Comment: More info is needed to offer any help. What are you trying to do and what version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @David When I want to change an icon, I want the directory /home/andy/ICONS/ to be selected.

Comment: Where do you want to change an icon?

Comment: @vanadium I change icons on the panel and desktop.

Comment: Please use "edit" to add any contextual clarifying information to the question. Is the directory you show in the picture the one that is opened by default?

Comment: @vanadium The directory opened sometimes changes depending on the program I want to change the icon for.